# animating array elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please Consider the following: 
**html**:

```
<div class="circle"> </div>
```

**css**:

```
.circle{
position:fixed;
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:none;
border-radius:50px;
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
background-color: red;}
```

**jquery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var cArray=[];
for(var i=0; i<7; i++){
var c=$('.circle').clone().appendTo('body');
cArray.push(c); 
}
animateCircle(cArray);
});

function getNewPosition(){
var h= $(window).height()-100;
var w= $(window).width()-100;

var nh=Math.floor(Math.random()*h);
var nw=Math.floor(Math.random()*w);

return [nh,nw];
 }

function animateCircle(cArr){

 $.each(cArr, function(index,value){          
 var newp = getNewPosition();
$(this).animate({   top: newp[0],left: newp[1],function(){animateCircle();}  });     

});

}
```

With the above code,i have created a circle,cloned it and added each new element to `cArray`as you can see.The problem is that all the cloned circles are animated only once,they're supposed to keep moving each time a new position is acquired,but obviously i got something wrong.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$(this).animate({   top: newp[0],left: newp[1],function(){animateCircle();}  }); ` is invalid Javascript.

Comment: i know there's something wrong,do you know how i can fix it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).animate({   top: newp[0],left: newp[1],function(){animateCircle();}  });
```

This is the problematic line. 1, there's a syntax error. 2, there's a logic error.

Syntax error, you didn't close the object in the right place.

```
$(this).animate({   top: newp[0],left: newp[1]}, function(){animateCircle();}); 
//                                            ^^
```

Logic error, `animateCircle` takes an argument with an array (`cArr`):

```
$(this).animate({top: newp[0], left: newp[1]}, function(){animateCircle(cArr);});
```